# how would I go about 'starting over from scratch' with Rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an existing Rails app that I built using Rails 3, Mongoid/Mongodb and Devise. The app is running fine. I'd now like to add some tests to it (sure, shoulda done this in the beginning but the learning curve for just Rails was enough...).

I've used several pages to get it going, especially the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) and [this blog post about Mongo and Cucumber/Rspec](http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/07/how-to-configure-cucumber-and-rspec-to-work-with-mongoid). My concern here is that between all of the "add this to this and such file" that I've done to try and get this working (and it's not) I've made such a mess of things that it might be better to start over from scratch. With the testing portion of the app.

I thought I would just delete the `spec` and `test` directories and re-gen the tests but I can't find a command to do that (the regen).

I've built a very simple test (assert true) but I'm getting:

```
D:/Dev/TheApp/test/test_helper.rb:10:in `<class:TestCase>': 
undefined method `fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I think the real issue here is that I'm using MongoDb and the test architecture in Rails seems to really really want to do ActiveRecord. Not sure if those two are compatible.

Is there a quick way to build a barebones test directory? My short term solution is to just roll back those directories. Hoping for a better solution.

Comment: You should add a mongodb tag, since it's probably the stickiest part of this question.

Comment: What do you mean "re-gen the tests"? Do you mean the boilerplate (empty) tests that rails generates when you `rails generate model User` ?

Comment: Also, do you want to write tests in Test::Unit or in RSpec?

Comment: @Jesse right I'm wondering if I can wipe the tests without wiping the model. Or just generate blank tests. Don't really have a preference for Rspec but it seems to be the way things are going.

Answer (score 0):

The blank tests are really worthless. If you didn't have tests/specs of value, then just start from scratch. And if you want to start over, you should just delete them and start new.

You could treat your code as "legacy code" as defined by Michael Feathers in [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) -- that is, code without tests.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this getting started with rails testing guide over at 10gen:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+-+Getting+Started#Rails-GettingStarted-Testing